# How to set Jquery UI to Dynamic maxWidth and maxHeight?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm working on a controls window that can be dragged and resized.  It should be able to be resized to be a really wide but short menu:

[Standard look of the controls, compact and then extended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADWAw.png)

This is in attempt to replicate a photo editor, where you can have a tools menu or settings menu that can be resized to be either really tall but thin (such as a sidebar), or really fat but short (such as a toolbar / menu bar).

What I want to accomplish:  I want to set jquery UI resizable to be the minimum and maximum size of the width and height of the inner content, at any point in time, so that the draggable is never too big or too small for the content inside of it, but it can still be dragged out as shown in the image above.

To be more specific, let me explain with minHeight. I want to set a minHeight of the size of the content, but this will only be the correct height when it is first sized, not when I drag the controls out:

[incorrect min height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCxfo.png)

(I put a green div around the content to visualize the actual size of the content, or how much room it takes up).  I want to lock the resizable to the red border.  I just need to know what this means in jQuery/css.

I tried code similar to this:

```
$( "#controls" ).resizable({
    minHeight: ($controls).height(),
```

});

where #controls is the div with the red border.

but this only sets the initial height.

Possible issues that could be causing the problem are:

1. Syntax problem.  Maybe it should be working but I messed something up.  I've only been working with jQuery for less than a week, so I am not super familiar with it.
2. The code above is only ran once, setting the minHeight only once to the height of the content in that moment of time.  A solution could be to set an event along the lines of "size changed--> update the minHeight"
3. I'm trying to make jQuery UI do something it was not designed to do.

Any help would be great!

Comment: a fiddle would be great to help you out. All 3 Options are possible. But I guess the 2. is your problem. But hard to say without actual code.